# Chat message duplication filter is over-aggressive

Tags: bug, chat

[In chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12823205#12823205), I wanted to post a link to a question, followed by a relevant YouTube video. Because I wasn’t paying attention, I posted the video first by mistake. No problem. I edited the existing comment to be the question instead, and then posted the video. Except that it wouldn’t post: nothing happened at all when I tried. I think it was the duplicate message filter preventing me from repeating myself, even though the previous message had been edited,

I posted a nonsense message, then the YouTube video, then deleted the nonsense. This worked, but should not have been necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That scenario makes sense to me. I believe this is by design.

The duplication filter is not really aggressive as much as it only considers the first state of the message. You can also duplicate by posting message a, then posting message b, then editing message b to be a.